# Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

I'm facing performance issues in my UWP app. When I run in debug mode, everything is ok. When I run the release build, it's is automatically built with .NET native toolchain. The app runs at least 5 times slower. When I run the release built without this setting, it runs just fine. This is weird because performance should improve with .NET native toolchain.

What I did next was installing the latest package of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (version 6.0.8). Before, the package was never included in my project, but the app was just running fine (except for the performance issue in release mode). So, I'm wondering if that package is needed to be referenced in my project since it's running without.

I also noticed another weird thing: The store is refusing packages built with Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.0.8. The version that was accepted is 5.1.0. Wondering why is that?

So, long story short, these are my questions:

- Do I need a reference to Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform in my project and which version?
- Would that help for the performance issues I'm having now?
- Why is my app refused by the store (preprocessing stage) when I include Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: how was your application even running without `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package ? and isn't it supposed to be added as soon as you create a new project ?

Comment: @Pratyay - I was also wondering how that is possible. I just have the following references : 'Analyzers' and 'Universal Windows'. But you're correct, when a new UWP project is created, it's added automatically. If I remember well, I removed it because my app was refused in the store, because of that. Error code '1201'. Maybe when there is no reference, it uses a internal reference, old version. From AppManifest.xml : <build:Item Name="ilc.exe" Version="1.4.24211.00 built by: PROJECTNGDR2" />. When I add the reference it's 1.7.... instead of 1.4...  Thanks !

Comment: So, for now, I added the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform reference again. But I'm still puzzled why I get a 'error 1201' when uploading to the store. Without that reference, the upload is fine.

Comment: What is the app doing? Which bits are slower? Have you tried profiling the app at all?

Comment: The app loads data from a webservice, processes it and sends it back to the webservice. There are a lot of input fields. I noticed that the standard UWP controls are fast. Found out that the delays are caused by third party components, even simple input fields. Strange thing is, the delays seems to disappear when the app is compiled with the latest relase of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. But don't know why the store refuses it, perhaps because the store uses an older version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. I replaced the components with standard controls. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I profiled the app. Delays were in the page load. thx